# HTTP Request sent to a Struts Action, encoding settings (Java)

Tags: javascript, java, encoding, struts

I am working on a Java application based on struts-framework. I have several Action classes which extend the class " Action". Sending POST Request via HTML-formula is working fine. I am using Javascript/Ajax to create a HTTP request like:

```
goMyAlertsCommandQueue.addAjaxCall({
    type : "POST",
    url : './showDetails.do',
    dataType : "html",
    data : ({
        Action : 'saveAlert',
        Title : title} ......
```

In the execute method in my action class I can access the attribute "title".
My problem is, if I have an input field, whose input I want to send to my action class, contains special charakters ,like "&", are converted to `&amp;amp;`. 
It is happening before anything in the action method is being executed.

I have tried to add "        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
" to my AjaxCall, but it hasnt helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Jakarta Commons Lang library's [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4(java.lang.String)) method is what you are looking for.

You should use this method in your Struts Action class.

For example, the string:

```
"&lt;Fran&ccedil;ais&gt; Happy &amp; Sad"
```

will become

```
"<Français> Happy & Sad"
```

Comment: thank you, I will try it. But it would be interesting to know what the reason is for this.

Comment: Could you please post your full ajax call with insertion of input value to it?

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. Before the ajax call is being called, the title has the following value :                                                                                               var title = jQuery("#AlertDetailsTitle").val(); // title = "Detractor DE|CT, MI| IMCP &"      Immediately before the execute method in the action class is executed, the value is :    Detractor DE|CT, MI| IMCP &amp;amp;                           And after StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml the value is converted to:  Detractor DE|CT, MI| IMCP &amp;

Comment: Please try with title = encodeURIComponent(jQuery("#AlertDetailsTitle").val());